# Curious about cout when there is a bus error on some next line

Tags: c++, cout, bus-error

I am curious about how cout work with bus/segmentation errors. I have two examples pasted below. Because I don't know how to replicate a bus error you have to take if from me that grid.DoMovement, in this example, throws a bus error. While I was cout-ing something before the bus error line I noticed that if I put an endline in it will print it out fine, but if I don't put an endl in it does not. The examples at the bottom show what I mean.

Why is it that if you don't put an endline in the cout and you have a bus error on one of the later lines that it doesn't print out the "example 2"?

Example 1:

```
std::cout << "example 1" << endl;
grid.DoMovement();
```

Output is

```
works
bus error
```

Example 2:

```
std::out << "example 2";
grid.DoMovement();
```

Output is

```
bus error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default IOStreams are buffered. Anything only written to the buffer won't be displayed. When you use `std::endl` with a stream a newline gets added and the stream is flushed. Note, that normally you **don't** want to have the stream flushed: Frequent flushing of flie streams can reduce performance dramatically! Thus, it is a good idea not to use `std::endl` but `'\n'` if you want a newline. If you really want to flush a stream you can explicitly use `std::flush` which just flushes the stream.

During debugging it may be helpful to have all output appear as soon as it is written so that a crash doesn't prevent output from showing. If you follow the above advise and don't flush frequently a lot of output may get buffered. The simple remedy for this is to use `std::unitbuf`: this manipulator turns on the flag `std::ios_base::unitbuf` cause the output streams to be flushed after each insertion. You can turn the flag off again using `std::nounitbuf` to avoid slowdown in code sections which are known to work (or, at least, known not to fail in a too dramatic way):

```
std::cout << std::unitbuf;   // turn on automatic flushing
problematic_code();
std::cout << std::nounitbuf; // turn off automatic flushing
```

The default settings for the `std::ios_base::unitbuf` is the differences between `std::cerr` and `std::clog`: both stream write to the standard error stream (on UNIXes file descriptor 2) but `std::cerr` flushes its buffer after each write while `std::clog` does not.

Answer (score 4):

The `std::endl` does not only add a new line to the stream, it also flush the current buffer of the output stream. If you get a bus error while some data is in the output stream buffer, you won't see the data.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is buffered when `std::cerr` is not.
If you tests with `std::cerr`, with or without `std::endl`, you'll see your message.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl

Answer (score 1):

`endl` is a "magical" manipulator that outputs the newline character and flushes the output buffer.

The buffer is also normally flushed when the program finishes, so you usually cannot see the additional effect of `endl`. But if your program crashes shortly thereafter, the buffers are not flushed, and the output doesn't appear.

You can change your second example to

```
std::out << "example 2" << flush;
```

to see the effect of flushing.